# Use of “heraus” in the phrase “aus der Situation heraus”

Tags: phrase, adverb

I'm confused by the use of word *heraus* in the following sentence:

> Dann entscheiden Sie aus der Situation heraus, wen Sie wem zuerst vorstellen.

What is the role of this word here? I noticed that dict.cc entry for English [out of](http://www.dict.cc/?s=out%20of) gives its translation as *aus … (heraus)*. Does it mean that *heraus* is optional here and can be dropped from the sentence? Or would it be wrong for some reason?

Comment: Since what you are actually asking about is the phrase *aus der Situation heraus*, I shortened your title accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure if the context is important or not here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a particle. The sentence has the same meaning without *heraus*, because *aus* already means *out of*.

Those particles can be confusing first but as soon you know the pairs (*aus/heraus*, *in/hinein*, *durch/hindurch*, *über/hinüber*, *auf/hinauf*, *unter/drunter* etc.) they can be quite helpful when listening to German. The crucial information is doubled.

People giving you directions are often going to use them to help you remember the way.

You don't have to use particles in your own speech but doing so will immediately make you sound more German. Just don't overdo it.

Comment: You can also add um/herum to your list.

Comment: *in/drin* (lit. **in**, as opposed to in/hinein which is **into**) also comes to mind. And *heraus* may be shortened to *raus*. Some dialects shorten the *hin*, too, so e.g. *hinauf* becomes *'nauf*. The type and amount of particle use and shortening is a marker for dialects and sociolects. No particles -> foreigner.